# rails 3.1 coffeescript file extension problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, coffeescript, assets, sprockets

I have this stock rails 3.1 app, before even adding anything, I was testing to see if the assets are working as advertised

so i created this app/assets/javascripts/test.coffee

where test.coffee is just a

alert "hi"

When I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/test.coffee, I do see

```
(function() {
  alert("hi");
}).call(this);
```

But if I do http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/test.js, I get routing error; but I thought this is the correct behavior, not the above one. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming your your js file to `test.js.coffee`

Coffee extension indicates that this file should be preprocessed with coffee processor, same as:

- `index.html.haml` is just `index.html` with haml processor or
- `style.css.sass` is just `style.css` with sass processor

Comment: Yup, it works. -- I actually did know about it; the reason I had to ask anyway is because I am using this rails-backbone plugin, which has generators that generate filename.coffee files under the app/assets/javascripts and have these generated files be required in the application.js file ( but it obviously didn't work; but then again, why would the author not append .js as well if he's good enough to make a gem). That's where I got confused and decided to try to access plain .coffee files. Here's that gem's git https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails

Comment: @Nik You probably can use just `assets/test` (without any extension) as javascript source and it should work, but I'm not sure about content type send with file without extension.

Comment: oh wow, it does work. And you don't find this funky that extension isn't required?. Anyway, For the purpose of this question, I do consider this answered.